# How do I flip the trendline patterns on my ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I want to make the Girls have the dashed trendline and the Boys have a solid trendline. I'd also like to remove the box around the graph, save the y and x-axis lines, and the shading behind the shapes on the key. I am using ggplot2 in R.

```
dr <- ggplot(DATASET, 
             aes(x=EC, 
                  y=sqrt_Percent.5, 
                  color=Sex1M, 
                  shape=Sex1M, 
                  linetype=Sex1M)) + 
    geom_point(size= 3, 
               aes(shape=Sex1M,                                                    
               color=Sex1M)) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,16))+
    geom_smooth(method=lm,
                se=FALSE,
                fullrange=TRUE) + 
    labs(x="xaxis title", 
        y = "yaxis title", 
        fill= "") + 
     xlim(3,7) + 
     ylim(0,10)  + 
    theme(legend.position = 'right', 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA, 
                                      color = 'white'),   
                                      panel.background = NULL,
                                      legend.background =element_rect(fill=NA,
              size=0.5,
              linetype="solid")) + 
scale_color_grey(start = 0.0,
                 end = 0.4)
```

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueWLS.jpg)

Comment: You can use `scale_linetype_manual` to set, well, the line types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change line type for certain categories in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184348/change-line-type-for-certain-categories-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 0):

There is quite something going on in your visualisation. One strategy to develop this is to add layer and feature by feature once you have your base plot.

There a different ways to change the "sequence" of your colours, shapes, etc.
You can do this in ggplot with one of the scale_xxx_manual layers.

Conceptually, I suggest you deal with this in the data and only use the scales for "twisting". But that is a question of style.
In your case, you use `Sex1M` as a categorical variable. There is a built in sequence for (automatic) colouring and shapes. So in your case, you have to "define" the levels in another order.

As you have not provided a representative sample, I simulate some data points and define Sex1M as part of the data creation process.

```
DATASET <- data.frame(
     x = sample(x = 2:7, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
   , y = sample(x = 0.2:9.8, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
   , Sex1M = sample(c("Boys", "Girls"), size = 20, replace = TRUE )
```

Now let's plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DATASET <- DATASET %>% 
   mutate(Sex1M = factor(Sex1M, levels = c("Boys","Girls))  # set sequence of levels: boys are now the first level aka 1st colour, linetype, shape.

# plot
ggplot(DATASET, 
       aes(x=x,    # adapted to simulated data 
           y=y,    # adapted to simulated data
           color=Sex1M,    # these values are now defined in the sequence
           shape=Sex1M,    # of the categorical factor you created
           linetype=Sex1M) # adapt the factor levels as needed (e.g change order)
    ) + 
    geom_point(size= 3, 
               aes(shape=Sex1M,                                                    
                   color=Sex1M)) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,16))+
    geom_smooth(method=lm,
                se=FALSE,
                fullrange=TRUE) + 
    labs(x="xaxis title", 
         y = "yaxis title", 
         fill= "") + 
    xlim(3,7) + 
    ylim(0,10)  + 
    theme(legend.position = 'right', 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA, 
                                      color = 'white'),   
          panel.background = NULL,
#------------ ggplot is not always intuitive - the legend background the panel 
# comprising the legend keys (symbols) and the labels
# you want to remove the colouring of the legend keys
          legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
# ----------- that can go. To see above mentioned difference of background and key
# set fill = "blue"
          # legend.background =element_rect(fill = NA, size=0.5,linetype="solid")
          ) + 
    scale_color_grey(start = 0.0,
                     end = 0.4)
```

The settings for the background panel make the outer line disappear in my plot.
Hope this helps to get you started.

[image]